# Resistor Divider PMOS Example Problem

Tags: mosfet, analog, fet

From Razavi's [*Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*](http://d1.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_44/ourdev_669891QWSQZ8.pdf), question 2.6a asks to plot \$I_x\$ vs. \$V_x\$ as \$V_x\$ varies from 0 to 3 V in the circuit below. The solution manual states that:

$$V_{sg} = (V_{dd} - V_x)\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

[image]

However, this doesn't seem right. I think instead:

$$V_{sg} = V_{dd} - (V_{dd} - V_x)\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

What should \$V_{sg}\$ be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resistor \$R_1\$ is connected between source and gate,
\begin{align*}
V_{SG}&=\mathrm{voltage\ across\ R_1}\\
&=\mathrm{I_{R1}\times R_1}\\
&=\frac{V_{DD}-V_x}{R_1+R_2}\times R_1
\end{align*}

Comment: I did this, but for some reason, I misunderstood this to be Vg (and hence why I did Vsg = Vdd - Vg = Vdd - (Vdd - Vx)*(voltage divider)).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's right. I'll give you a couple of hints and hope you get them. The voltage \$V_{SG}\$ is equal to \$V_{DD}-V_G\$. Now what's \$V_{G}\$? Apply KCL at the gate and solve for \$V_{G}\$.

Also sometimes it's worth checking your solution to find out if it makes sense. For example, in terms of your own formula if you put \$V_{DD}=V_x\$, then \$V_{SG}\$ will be equal to \$V_{DD}\$!! But how can that be possible? The voltage across source-gate is equal to the voltage across \$R_1\$. Because the latter is zero the former will also be 0V. So sometimes it's good to check your formulas.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and got the correct answer. My mistake was in thinking that Vg = (Vdd - Vx) * (R2/(R1+R2)). When in reality, the voltage divider would produce: Vg = *Vx* + (Vdd - Vx) * (R2/(R1+r2)).